# Custom iComparer

Tags: c#, sorting

I've got a base class `GraphUIControl` which is inherited by 4 child classes:

- `BubbleGraphUIControl`
- `BatchGraphUIControl`
- `LineGraphUIControl`
- `StackedGraphUIControl`

I sometimes put all my `GraphUIControl` in the same `List<GraphUIControl>` for some obscure reasons.

I wanted to order my list (first by Graph type, then by name) so I implemented my custom `iComparer`:

```
public class GraphUIControlComparer : IComparer<GraphUIControl>
{
    public int Compare(GraphUIControl x, GraphUIControl y)
    {
        if (x.GetType() == y.GetType())
        {
            return String.Compare(x.Parent.Name, y.Parent.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal);
        }
        if (x is BubbleGraphUIControl)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (y is BubbleGraphUIControl)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (x is BatchGraphUIControl)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (y is BatchGraphUIControl)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (x is LineGraphUIControl)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (y is LineGraphUIControl)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (x is StackedGraphUIControl)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        if (y is StackedGraphUIControl)
        {
            return 1;
        }       
        return 0;
    }
}
```

But it seems very verbose and I'd love to make it shorter (also, as it's my first `iComparer`, if I made a mistake/nonsense/whatever, don't hesitate to tell me!)

#### Example:

Let's take `A, A1, A2, B & C` as :

- A is a `BubblueGraphUIControl`
- A1 is a `BubblueGraphUIControl`
- A2 is a `BubblueGraphUIControl`
- C is a `LineGraphUIControl`
- B is a `StackedGraphUIControl`

I put it in the list named `myList` in random mode. When I do `myList.Sort(new GraphUIControlComparer())` I want `myList` to be in the order `A, A1, A2, C, B` because of the types order following this rule:

1. `BubbleGraphUIControl`
2. `BatchGraphUIControl`
3. `LineGraphUIControl`
4. `StackedGraphUIControl`

Then the `A, A1, A2` are in alphabetic order.

Comment: I delete my answer, hope someone help you. Probably I don't understood the logic behind this compare.

Comment: @mybirthname if you don't understood it means that I explained it bad. I'll edit my post with an example :)

Comment: I see where @mybirthname went wrong now. There are only four types, so saying X is one of those four types will always return 1. Yes. You've got a pickle here, but this solution isn't all that bad. I'm interested to see if anyone has another solution, because i don't see one that would look as clean as what you've already done.

Comment: Now I understood you, thanks for the explanation !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under most circumstances, it's a good idea to avoid `GetType()`. Using it indicates something's wrong with your design. But if you're willing to use it, there's a very interesting way to write this (I won't say it's good, it's just interesting and short):

```
public class GraphUIControlComparer : IComparer<GraphUIControl>
{
    private int NameCompare(GraphUIControl x, GraphUIControl y)
    {
        return String.Compare(x.Parent.Name, y.Parent.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal);
    }

    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, int> typeLookupDict
      = new Dictionary<Type,int>
      {
         {typeof(BubbleGraphUIControl), 0},
         {typeof(BatchGraphUIControl), 1},
         {typeof(LineGraphUIControl), 2},
         {typeof(StackedGraphUIControl), 3}
      };

    private int TypeLookup(GraphUIControl x)
    {
       return typeLookupDict[x.GetType()];
    }

    public int Compare(GraphUIControl x, GraphUIControl y)
    {
        int tx = TypeLookup(x);
        int ty = TypeLookup(y);
        if (tx == ty)
        {
            return NameCompare(x,y);
        }
        return (tx < ty ? -1 : 1);
    }
}
```

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4287537/checking-if-the-object-is-of-same-type

Comment: Interesting solution. I like the lookup, but I think you're right. It has both advantages and disadvantages compared to the original code. ++

Comment: This is more or less what I thought when I saw the question. Note you could just do `return tx.CompareTo(ty)` for the final line.